# Как сделать подсветку синтаксиса kivy .kv для sublime text 3?

Tags: python, sublime-text, sublime-text-3, kivy, syntax

Как сделать подсветку в .kv для sublime text 3?
Я знаю что ее можно как-то написать, но моих знаний на это пока еще не хватает, прошу помогите) Очень уж не удобно писать без подсветки и синтаксиса)

Comment: Советую вам использовать IDE pycharm.И проблем с подсветкой синтаксиса не будет )

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/SublimeText/comments/2lli0l/syntax_highlighting_for_kv_language_kivy/